# @html.dropdownlist not populating the selected value

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, html-select

Here I have two dropdownlists. First one to display the list of countries and the second to list the states value for selected country from first. The list of values are populated from 
properly but in the dropdownlist, the values are not populated.
**jQuery:**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Country").change(function () {
            var Id = $('#Country option:selected').attr('value');
            $("#Region").empty();
            $.getJSON("/ControllerName/GetRegionList",{ ID: Id  },
                function (data) {                    
                    jQuery.each(data, function (key) {
                        $("#Region").append($("<option></option>").val(ID).html(Name));
                    });
                });
        });
    });
```

**View :**

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Country", new SelectList(Model.CountryList, "Value", "Text", Model.CountryList.SelectedValue))
 @Html.DropDownList("Region", new SelectList(Model.RegionList, "Value", "Text", Model.RegionList.SelectedValue))
```

**Controller:**

```
      public List<Region> GetRegionList(int ID)
        {
            int countryid = ID;           
            AddressModel objmodel = new AddressModel();
            List<Region> objRegionList = new List<Region>();
            objRegionList.Add(new Region { ID = "0", Name = " " });
            if (countryid != 0)
            {
                countryid = Convert.ToInt32(ID);
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("USP_ProcedureName", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", countryid);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mode", "Region");
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    if (dr["RegionId"].ToString() != "")
                    {
                        objRegionList.Add(new Region { ID = dr["RegionId"].ToString(), Name = dr["Name"].ToString() });
                    }
                }
                dr.Close();
                con.Close();
            }
            return objRegionList;
        }
```

What is the mistake in my code.? Any Suggestions.
EDIT : Added the snapshot
[image: empty ddl]

Comment: Attach your debugger to verify that Model.CountryList does indeed contain elements. Also, if Html.DropDownList(...) is the problem, you should be able to simplify the troubleshooting process by removing the jQuery code.

Comment: Yes. Model.CountryList contains elements and the till return objRegionlist can be tracked with list of elements.

Comment: Instead of passing a SelectList, could you try passing a plain IEnumerable<SelectListItem>. Something like Model.RegionList.Select(region => new SelectListItem { Text = region.Name, Value = region.Id })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ASP.NET MVC controller actions must return ActionResults. In your case you could return JSON:

```
public ActionResult GetRegionList(int id)
{
    var objRegionList = new List<Region>();
    objRegionList.Add(new Region { ID = "0", Name = " " });
    if (countryid != 0)
    {
        int countryid = ID;
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection("YOUR CONNECTION STRING COMES HERE"))
        using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            con.Open();

            cmd.CommandText = "USP_ProcedureName";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", countryid);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mode", "Region");
            using (var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    if (dr["RegionId"].ToString() != "")
                    {
                        objRegionList.Add(new Region 
                        { 
                            ID = dr["RegionId"].ToString(), 
                            Name = dr["Name"].ToString() 
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return Json(objRegionList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Notice that I have also cleared your code from unused variables and unnecessary `Convert.ToInt32` calls and most importantly wrapped IDisaposable resources such as SQL connections, commands and data readers in `using` statements to avoid leaking resources.

Then include the url of the controller action as a `data-*` attribute on the first dropdown to avoid ugly hardcoding it in your javascript and breaking when you deploy your application in IIS in a virtual directory:

```
@Html.DropDownList(
    "Country", 
    new SelectList(Model.CountryList, "Value", "Text", Model.CountryList.SelectedValue),
    new { data_url = Url.Action("GetRegionList", "ControllerName") }
)
```

finally adapt (simplify) your javascript:

```
$('#Country').change(function () {
    var regionDdl = $('#Region');
    regionDdl.empty();
    var id = $(this).val();
    var url = $(this).data(url);
    $.getJSON(url, { id: id }, function (data) {                    
        $.each(data, function (index, region) {
            regionDdl.append(
                $('<option/>', {
                    value: region.ID,
                    html: region.Name
                })
            );
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Darin for helping to write clean code. But still I face the same prob. Please check my edit.